# AWS CDK - compile-time programmatic extraction of account ID from ARN string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have the ARN of a downstream resource of an external AWS account. My infrastructure code is in AWS CDK. In my code, I want to extract the accountId from the ARN. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be elegantly done using the core cdk library. Here's the solution:

```js
import { Arn } from 'monocdk';
import arn = require("monocdk/lib/core/lib/arn");

private static getAccountIdFromArn(arn: string): string {
        const arnComponents = Arn.parse(arn)
        if(undefined === arnComponents.account) {
            throw new Error(`account id not present in the arn @{arn}!`)
        }
        return arnComponents.account
    }
```